# How to create a checkbox in a server generated pdf?

Tags: node.js, checkbox, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I'm using [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.org) to create PDFs in my application. I need to design a form which includes check-boxes and I couldn't find any library which supports check-boxes in PDF.

Is it possible to make check-boxes in the PDF when generating through the server. If yes which library can be used to achieve this functionality.

For my particular case I'm not looking for a clickable checkbox. A simple checkbox either checked or unchecked will work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you got any answer to this? I'm looking for the same. Upvoted your question for better reach

Comment: No haven't found anything yet to solve this. If you get any information regarding this please update this question. @WiselyDCruizer

Comment: I have implemented an workaround solution for the checkbox. which is using the same pdfmake functionality. If you have found an alternate solution its well and good.

Comment: Can you please share your workaround solution to make a checkbox using the same pdfmake functionality?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas here, just to sum up some investigations I made recently:

- you can build one yourself, with a combination of tables (maybe setting the borders only for the cell including the ✓ symbol) and Unicodes character, but you'll need a font on the server supporting them
- PdfMake [supports SVGs](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/svgs/) so you can get a checkbox svg and use it inline (maybe in combination with columns, margins and so on to make it work with a label)